# What is the most accurate method to calculate wire cross section according to voltage drop on AC distribution systems?

Tags: three-phase, voltage, split-phase

If we go for the intuitive way you should first calculate resistance of conductors based on temperature and construction properties but I don't get how to integrate that with the format of current or power on three or split phase for example the sqrt(3), but have you ever seen those cross section formulas for Mono-Split-Three phase.

Vdrop = I(amps)*(Impedance(ohms/ft))*distance.

This is the basic formula and it works well for mono or DC.

But,
for example you can calculate cross-section of mono using:

S = (4.distance.current)/alloweddrop.voltage.

What's the deduction?

Comment: The deduction appears to be you don't know the difference between an estimate that appears to be based on some particular units and conductor material, and a formula that presents them all explicitly. Assuming the validity of your formula for S, it would be interesting to compare it with the other, and see what set of built in assumptions make them consistent. What units are required to make the '4' the correct scaling factor for instance?

Comment: Bear in mind that while physics will give the 'most accurate' way to calculate a voltage drop, whether the drop is correct for a given scenario and a location in the world will likely be covered by regulations, which may only have a nodding acquaintance with physics.